# ColdFusion Server Monitoring - Not Working

Tags: windows, coldfusion, monitoring

I am trying to launch the ColdFusion Server Monitor on a Windows Server 2003 (Web Edition) machine running ColdFusion 8 (ver. 8,0,0,176276). It is running in stand-alone configuration.

The pop-up window launches as http://www.mydomain.com/CFIDE/administrator/monitor/launch-monitor.cfm. However, I get a Flash dialogue box then with the error information 'ColdFusion Server is unavailable'. The dialogue box also has a place to fill out the server details (such as port number and username/password). All of this info seems in order, and again the error message is to do with it thinking that ColdFusion is not running. Obviously the CF server is available, but perhaps the server monitor can't see it.

The interesting thing is that on some other boxes we have that run Windows Web Server 2008 and the same version of CF, we have NO PROBLEMS launching the CF Server Monitor.

Obviously I am missing something here. Has anyone come across this issue. Any and all replies are greatly appreciated!

---

Thanks Iain - many thanks for your reply.

I can usually go to a particular machine's sub-domain to launch start CF admin and run the monitoring, for example:

http://server1.mydomain.com/CFIDE/administrator/

Here I enter the my usual CF admin password. Then when I click the 'Launch Server Monitor' button it should just popup a new window. I would expect it to use the same credentials as other servers that do work, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to log onto the server using terminal servers and try this? Is that what you are suggesting?

But one thing that makes me think it may not be credentials is the fact I get that 'ColdFusion Server is unavailable' message on the Flash dialogue. This suggests there is perhaps another problem.

Does anyone know are there any log files for the server monitoring I can take a look at? I need to understand why I am getting this message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** FURTHER EDIT **

Adobe have created a new technote to address this issues at 
http://www.adobe.com/go/kb407866

** ORIGINAL POST **

I posted this same question on the Adobe forums and that great Coldfusion community stalwart Charlie Arehart posted a solution :)

Essentially the problem is an IIS configuration one, but Charlie has mentioned a few pitfalls to look out for.

Here is the [Adobe forums post](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/webforums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=143&threadid=1404093&forumid=1).

And here is [Charlie's solution](http://carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2008/11/7/cf911_cf8mon_cf_unavailable).

I hope this helps anyone else who encounters this problem.

** EDIT **

Another solution that works well, especially if the above solution breaks your custom 404 error pages is to simply create the flex2gateway (case important) directory under your web root. No need to restart IIS or CF. Creating this directory will also not interfere with working servers, so it can be added to your repository with no ill effects.

Thanks,
Ciarán

Comment: Afraid not, busy getting the house ready for the imminent arrival of the overlord of the known universe (i.e first child due in 3 weeks or so). Make the most of it for me, and if you happen to fond yourself in a beer garden, sink a cold one of me :)

Comment: Haha, I'm on that train too - our first due in February. Enjoy the ride as they say! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this where you need to launch the shortcut from the profile that installed the CF server app. Either that or you have a typo in credentials, compare to a working one or try domain\user or .\user

hope that helps