# ColdFusion 10 Server Monitor Doesn't Load

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a server that we just upgraded to ColdFusion 10. I went to view the Server Monitor, and I'm just getting a gray screen with no detail information about the server:

[image: View of the Server Monitor in the browser]

I've checked to make sure that the flex2gateway URL returns a blank screen (so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261614/coldfusion-server-monitoring-not-working) isn't the solution).

When I look at the requests in Charles, everything appears to be returning correctly (as far as I can tell). Every POST returns a `200 OK`, and it looks like I'm getting valid AMF responses from the server:

[image: View of activity from Charles]

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you look at the net tab with firebug to see where it might be dying at?

Comment: I've updated the question with some information from Charles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a broken Flash player. Does Flash content load on other sites?

Comment: I'm running the very latest flash player, and flash movies are playing fine on Adobe.com. That being said, now that you mention it... I tested the server monitor in Chrome, and it's loading fine there. So it very well may be an issue with the Flash Player in Safari.

Comment: Sure enough, a reinstall of the Flash Player and restart of Safari fixed the issue... I should have thought to test in other browsers before I asked the question... Thanks :)

Comment: Sweet! Glad that's fixed :-)